# I can't center a LI items

Tags: html, css

I cannot center LI items in unordered list. I've tried all possible solutions but it doesn't work. **Nav options class** is just a container for UL list. *Results are attached in the attachment*.

```
.header-start .top-nav .center .nav-options {
   width: 80%;
   height: 100%;
   margin: auto;
   background: red;
}

.header-start .top-nav .center .nav-options .items {
   display: flex;
   list-style: none;
   text-align: center;
   margin: auto;
}

.header-start .top-nav .center .nav-options .items li a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #fff;
   font-weight: 100;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 13px;
}
```

[Here's a results of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4sDB.png)

Comment: Can you provide the `html` too please ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
.header-start .top-nav .center .nav-options .items {
   display: flex;
   list-style: none;
   justify-content: center;
   margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you. I love you bro

Answer (score 0):

Try add this line at ".header-start .top-nav .center .nav-options .items":

```
    width: fit-content;
```

The result would be:

```
.header-start .top-nav .center .nav-options .items {
    width: fit-content;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```